# Android cannot create ViewDragHelper

Tags: android

I have been hit by a problem today trying to create a `ViewDragHelper` as it is shown in this tutorial http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/ and this http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/ .I kinda want to reproduce a `draggable layout` from the bottom of the screen to the top, like SoundCloud application.

When I am trying to create the `ViewDragHelper` I receive the following 2 errors:

```
dragHelper = new ViewDragHelper.create(this, 1.0f, new ViewDragHelper.Callback());

Cannot resolve symbol 'create'
'Callback' is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

I have searched over the internet this problem but I couldn't resolve it only with a project clean and rebuild. I have took a look on gradle to see any uncommon imports that could disturb the import.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'net.koofr:java-koofr:1.2.8'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
```

Comment: `'Callback' is abstract; cannot be instantiated` this means you can only extend this class.

Comment: And how it should be used because everything I've read is different